# How to pass multi value parameter to SSRS from asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I am hooking up a site with an embeded ReportViewer control. I need to pass a Multi-value parameter (string data type) to the report. I have tried using the following methods but each time the report errors with a parameter is missing a value.

here is the method I am using:

```
string s = String.Join(",", paramValue.ToArray());
// method 2 carriage return new line delimited string

string s = String.Join("/r/n", paramValue.ToArray()) + "/r/n";
// method 3 values as a string array

string[] s = paramValue.ToArray();
paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("ParamName", s, false));
```

Obviously the above code is not exactly what I am using but it does show the variations I have tried.

None of the above works. please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add it as an Array to the `Values` property of type `StringCollection` .

```
 List<ReportParameter> rptParams = new List<ReportParameter>();
    ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter("ParamName");

    string[] values = new string[]{"a", "b", "c"};

    param.Values.AddRange(values);

    rptParams.Add(param);

    this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rptParams);
```

Comment: It works for one report, but unfortunately not working for another report. here is the code for my second report.