# How to Correctly Pass Multi-Value Integer Parameters When Running SSRS Reports from C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am working on a C# console application that runs SSRS reports and attaches the result to an email.  It can currently handle one value per report parameter and I am now attempting to add the ability to send multiple values in report parameters.  At this point the parameters and their matching values are stored in a Dictionary and then each is added to the report parameters before rendering/running the report.  When sending only one ID in a parameter value, the report filters as expected but it would appear that sending more than one value in a parameter causes the filtering to fail somewhere in the processing that happens on the SSRS server and the result that comes back is an unfiltered report.

In the code samples provided below there are two report parameters, `@DriverID` and `@CustomerID` which can accept one or more integer values.  In the report design file these parameters are set as Text type parameters and allow multiple values is set TRUE.  These two parameters are actually integer parameters and when sending multiple values, I'm placing a comma separated list of integers into the parameter value.  From what I've read while troubleshooting, this approach seems to be the way several people say to handle multi-value parameters, but my results thus far seem to be proving that is not true.

**Report Data Set Query:**

```sql
SELECT O.OrderNum
    , FirstName = ISNULL(DTC.FirstName, DOR.FirstName)
    , LastName = ISNULL(DTC.LastName, DOR.LastName)
    , Shipper = C.Name
    , WorkType = TCWT.Name
    , StartTimeCST = dbo.fnUTC_to_Local(TCB.StartTimeUTC, 1, 1)
    , TCB.Notes
    , DurationMins = ISNULL(TCB.TotalMinutes, 0)
    , DurationHrs = CAST(ISNULL(ROUND((TCB.TotalMinutes / 60.0), 2), 0.0) AS DECIMAL(8,2))
FROM tblOrder O
    LEFT JOIN viewTimeCardBase TCB ON TCB.OrderID = O.ID
    LEFT JOIN tblCustomer C ON C.ID = O.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN tblDriver DTC ON DTC.ID = TCB.DriverID
    LEFT JOIN tblDriver DOR ON DOR.ID = O.DriverID
    LEFT JOIN tblTimeCardWorkType TCWT ON TCWT.ID = TCB.WorkTypeID
WHERE (TRIM(ISNULL(@OrderNum,'')) = '' OR @OrderNum = NULL OR O.OrderNum = @OrderNum)
    AND (TCB.DriverID IN(@DriverID))
    AND (O.CustomerID IN(@CustomerID))
    AND (ISNULL(O.OrderDate, O.DueDate) BETWEEN ISNULL(@StartDate, '1900-01-01') AND ISNULL(@EndDate, '2099-12-31'))
```

**Report Generation Code:**

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> reportParams = GetSsrsReportParameters(reportDefinition, predefinedParameters);
using (SsrsReportService rs = new SsrsReportService())
{
    rs.ReportServerURL = SsrsConnectionHelper.ServerUrl;
    rs.Domain = SsrsConnectionHelper.WindowsDomain;
    rs.Username = SsrsConnectionHelper.WindowsUsername;
    rs.Password = SsrsConnectionHelper.WindowsPassword;
    rs.DocumentName = report.ReportName;
    rs.ReportPath = "/" + report.ReportName;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in reportParams)
    {
        rs.Parameters.Add(new ReportParameter(param.Key, param.Value));
    }

    ServerReport serverReport = rs.PrepareReport();

    byte[] bytes = serverReport.Render
                   (
                      "EXCELOPENXML",  // Can also be "PDF"
                      null,
                      out string mimeType,
                      out string encoding,
                      out string filenameExtension,
                      out string[] streamids,
                      out Warning[] warnings
                   );

    email.AttachmentStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
}
```

**Method to Build the Report Parameter List:**

```cs
private static Dictionary<string, string> GetSsrsReportParameters(SsrsReportDefinition reportDefinition
    , List<SsrsReportParameter_SupportDB> predefinedParameters)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the user defined parameter names and desired values from the report definition
        Dictionary<string, string> userDefinedParamValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string keyValuePair in reportDefinition.ParameterValues.Split(','))
        {
            string[] kvp = keyValuePair.Split('=');
            userDefinedParamValues.Add(kvp[0], kvp[1]);
        }

        // Check parameters & build a list of valid parameters and values to send to SSRS
        Dictionary<string, string> validParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (SsrsReportParameter_SupportDB parameter in predefinedParameters)
        {
            // If the user defined parameter name matches the predefined parameter name, add it and its value to the valid parameters list
            string value;
            if (userDefinedParamValues.TryGetValue(parameter.ParameterName, out value))
            {
                if (parameter.Required && string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    // If a required parameters is null or blank, throw an error
                    throw new ArgumentException("The value for a required SSRS report parameter has been left blank.", parameter.ParameterName);
                }

                // If the parameter is of type DateTime, use the offset date format and processing to determine the desired date value
                if (parameter.SsrsReportParameterTypeID == (int)SsrsReportParameterType_SupportDB.TYPE.DateTime)
                {
                    value = Core.DateHelper.ToOffsetDateTime(value).ToString();
                }

                // If the report parameter is a multi-select parameter it may include more than one value separated by pipes.
                // Pipes need to be converted to commas before setting the parameter value.
                if (value.Contains("|"))
                {
                    value = value.Replace("|", ",");
                }

                // Add the parameter but remove the at (@) symbol from the beginning of the parameter name
                validParameters.Add(parameter.ParameterName.Replace("@", ""), value);
            }
            else if (parameter.Required)
            {
                // If a required parameter is missing, throw an error
                throw new ArgumentException("A required SSRS report parameter is missing.", parameter.ParameterName);
            }
        }

        return validParameters;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The expected result is a filtered report that includes only results that are in the list of customer ID's and the list of driver ID's passed in the parameter values.  The actual result when passing more than one value for either parameter is an unfiltered report.  So far I am not getting any error messages when debugging the application.

Additionally, I can successfully run and filter the same SSRS report from a web application that connects to the same SSRS server and uses Report Viewer. 
 When selecting multiple values from the drop-down for the two parameters the result in Report Viewer is a filtered report as expected.

My conclusion at this point in the debugging process is that I'm not approaching multi-values parameters correctly in the console app.

*Clarification questions are welcome and I'll edit my question accordingly if I've not stated something clearly.*

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://deadlyembrace.net/multivalue-ssrs-report-parameters-from-c

Comment: ...here is a similar post from StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002218/how-to-pass-multi-value-parameter-to-ssrs-from-asp-net-c  `AddRange()` seems to be the answer in both posts

Comment: Thank you @DavidTansey, those links helped me out.  The using the `AddRange()` method was the missing piece to my puzzle.